# Toast notification does not disappear after clicking outside of it in .net WPF application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, trayicon

I am working on a .NET WPF project using Visual Studio 2022 and I added tray icon functionality to my app. I also show toast notification whenever my app is minimized to windows tray. Everything works fine except when I click outside border of toast notification, it does not disappear. I think it is a focus issue but can not able to overcome that. Any idea how to solve this?

My code:

```
    public NotifyIcon m_notifyIcon;
     public MainWindow()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                    m_notifyIcon = new NotifyIcon();
                    m_notifyIcon.BalloonTipText = "The app has been minimised. Click the tray icon to show.";
                    m_notifyIcon.BalloonTipTitle = "The App";
                    m_notifyIcon.Text = "The App";
                    m_notifyIcon.DoubleClick += new EventHandler(m_notifyIcon_Click);
                    m_notifyIcon.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(Notifier_MouseDown);
                    Hide();
                    if (m_notifyIcon != null)
                        m_notifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(2000);
                    CheckTrayIcon();
                }
            }
    
    
    
    private WindowState m_storedWindowState = WindowState.Normal;
            void OnStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
            {
                if (WindowState == WindowState.Minimized)
                {
                    Hide();
                    if (m_notifyIcon != null)
                        m_notifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(2000);
                }
                else
                    m_storedWindowState = WindowState;
            }
            void OnIsVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
            {
                CheckTrayIcon();
        }
    
        void m_notifyIcon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Show();
            WindowState = m_storedWindowState;
        }
        void CheckTrayIcon()
        {
            ShowTrayIcon(true);
        }
    
        void ShowTrayIcon(bool show)
        {
            if (m_notifyIcon != null)
                m_notifyIcon.Visible = show;
        }
    
        void Notifier_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                ContextMenu menu = (ContextMenu)this.FindResource("NotifierContextMenu");
                menu.IsOpen = true;
                IntPtr handle = ((HwndSource)PresentationSource.FromVisual(menu)).Handle;
                ApiHelper.SetForegroundWindow(handle);
            }
        }
```

Comment: If you can be sure users are win10+ you could use the win10 toast mechanism instead. Or at least you could with a regular wpf app. Not 100% sure with notifyicon.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, there are some users with win8 as well.

Comment: Might possibly still work. Install-Package Notifications.Wpf

Comment: Indeed, I need to do this without adding, installing external packages, libraries etc. Is not it possible to work around this without adding external resources?

Comment: nuget packages are just dll. I think that might just be one 25k dl